# Understanding JavaScript better

Tags: javascript, date, time

How does this code, know that today is Tuesday?

```
var today = new Date ();
var day = today.getDay();
var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
```

Comment: [Have you looked at the Date API?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: today is a Date object initialized to the current system date by default. Date.getDay() returns a zero-based integer representing the day of the week, starting with Sunday.

Comment: You should take a course on the language if you can't understand that easily. I don't say that to be demeaning, but it looks like you'll get stuck on the very next thing, and you'll lose your time if you have to ask a question here each time.

Comment: This looks like a good opportunity to use a debugger and step through your code, line by line, as it executes and examine the runtime values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have read the manual for [`.getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay):

> The value returned by `getDay()` is an integer corresponding to the day of the week: `0` for Sunday, `1` for Monday, `2` for Tuesday, and so on.

The above explains all. The `Date` object gets the current date (and time) from the system, which is the basic thing, and then has every details about the Day, Month, Year, Week, Week number, etc. Also, to debug your code, it has the following:

```
var today = new Date();
// Returns `Tue Jan 05 2016 16:30:25 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)`.
var day = today.getDay();
// Returns `2`, meaning it is Tuesday.
var daylist = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
// Okay, your array.
console.log("Today is : " + daylist[day] + ".");
// This is translated to `daylist[2]`, and Daylist's `2` has Tuesday.
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, im sorry if my questions seems stupid, theres a lot that i don't know about java script and i am just trying to learn as much as possible.

Comment: @Munkiuke While you learn, this would have been explained. I don't know how you missed it. Let me know if you have further questions about this.

Comment: I've just checked Munkiuke's post history and it looks like he's learning from codeacademy. He also produced a very strange use example of this, so I'm questioning their course's quality. Munkiuke, I think either the course is bad or you're lacking generic computer science culture. I would recommend either following codeacademy's suggested required courses or trying another MOOC platform. Anyway good luck in your search of knowledge !

Comment: I am not sure that i saw it, i took the course on code academy. and thanks. i got it now.

Comment: @Munkiuke Okay.. That's fine. Kindly learn to look at the docs at MDN... They have all the stuff you need.

Comment: @PraveenKumar how so? I looked into his post history in a bid to help him, and it looks like the codeacademy's course isn't clear enough to him. Now I don't know codeacademy's quality, so I suggest that there is either a problem with their course or that he lacks some pre-requisite to understand it easily. I didn't mean to offend, but I'd be glad to remove my comment if you have a better way to phrase it

Comment: @Aaron That's bad - CodeAcademy's not yours.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't think that forbids me from discussing the way someone learns from it, does it? All I'm trying to do is suggest solutions here. I'm pretty sure CodeAcademy's owners, or the one who published the specific course are not saying their tool/service can teach anything to anyone. While pedagogy is quite off-topic here, I think we can still discuss it in comments.

Comment: @Aaron Man, you **never** offended anyone. Thanks. I said, CodeAcademy is bad, and we need to let them know of this issue so that they can do well.

Comment: @PraveenKumar oh wow, I totally misunderstood you, I was about to ask you if you were affiliated with codeacademy and trying to bully me into silence ;) Sorry about the misunderstanding ! I'll try to find their specific course and notify them

Comment: @Aaron That's awesome. I appreciate your help in notifying them.